# Do diamond moderator flag dismissals always remove posts from all review queues?

Tags: support, review, flags

Recently there was [some confusion in a meta discussion](//meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6129/is-something-wrong-yes-too-much-moderation/6131?noredirect=1#comment18032_6131) about whether a ♦ mod dismissing a flag (as helpful or declined) would remove the flagged post from corresponding review queues. [Edits in the Low Quality Posts queue clear out the flag and don't generate any dispute flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230665/) implies that at least Community ♦ action does this, while [What happens when I flag a posted answer as “not an answer”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253244/what-happens-when-i-flag-a-posted-answer-as-not-an-answer/253449#253449) states that this happens for NAA, but it's not clear how reliable or general this is, and this particular point doesn't show up in either of its listed references. (For that matter, [When is a post removed from a review queue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164288/when-is-a-post-removed-from-a-review-queue) purports to be complete, and [doesn't list flag dismissal either](//meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/190581/9).)

So… under what circumstances do flag dismissals propagate to dequeue posts from review?

Comment: As a sanity check, consider that flagging has no connection to the suggested edit queue...

Comment: @Shog9: Well, sure. "Corresponding" review queues, if you like, and I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, that's a lot less paranoid than "all"... ;-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Posts are removed from the review queues when the conditions which put them there are no longer true.

Answers pop into the Low Quality Posts queue because they have an active Not An Answer or Very Low Quality flag on them. If those flags get dismissed and are no longer active, then that condition is no longer true and the review task will eventually end up formally invalidated whenever the system rechecks for qualified posts again.

Similarly, if a question was bumped into the Close Votes review queue due to a close flag, the review item will end up invalidated if that flag ends up aging away and there are no other close votes/flags on the question (note that moderators cannot explicitly dismiss recommend closure flags).